# Is there any way to process text file data using wso2 6.4.0?

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

How to fetch the data from text file using wso2 6.4.0? suggest me the ideas and samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [File Connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/File+Connector) to the EI which can do the file operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen on a directory and fetch & process the files real time, you can use file inbound endpoint. Please find the documentation below:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/File+Inbound+Protocol